# How to extract json from a json string using GSON?

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

Below is my JSON String. I am trying to extract `hosts` from it.

```
{"description":"DescA","process_running":"sf","hosts":{"dc1":["machineA","machineB"]}}
```

Since hosts is a JSON String in itself and I would like to extract that JSON String from it. I am using GSON here -

```
String ss = new String(bytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

// here ss is the above JSON String

Map<String, Object> data = gson.fromJson(ss, Map.class); // parse
```

I was trying to use `Map` to deserialize but the result it coming like this in the data-

```
{description=DescA, process_running=sf, hosts={dc1=[machineA, machineB]}}
```

Is there any way, I can extract `hosts` in the JSON format?

Comment: You want to deserialize it from Json, but not actually? Best I can think of is deserialize the entirety into a custom object, then serialize back with just the hosts piece of that object.

Comment: First go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  Then deserialize and access.  (Based on your listing above, "host" is not an embedded JSON string but just a JSON object containing element "dc1" which is an array.)

Comment: @HotLicks: Thanks for correcting me. I mixed up few terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of to do this would be to use gson to create a tree of json elements from your map, and ask it to give you just the hosts node:

```
    Map<String, Object> data = gson.fromJson(ss, Map.class); // parse

    JsonObject jsonTree = (JsonObject) gson.toJsonTree(data);
    String hostsJson = jsonTree.get("hosts").toString();
```